# Languages with immutable variables by default, like Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, referential-transparency

one thing that I find fascinating about Haskell is how functions and variables are the same. In most languages a variable holds a value while a function does something and then, eventually, returns a value. In Haskell you don't see this difference and after having used Haskell, falling back to more "traditional" programming where variables are different from functions or methods feels awkward. If I want to get a value, I shouldn't really worry about its origin, whether it is a constant value, a mutable variable or the result of a complex computation! In Haskell, **variables are just 0-ary functions**.

Many object-oriented languages have properties that feels a bit the gap.

Can anyone indicate any other language with a system similar to Haskell? I thought it was common to functional languages because of *referential transparency*, but I've seen it's not the case. In Lisp, for example, you have `(defun)` to explicitly declare functions.

Comment: In Haskell, `f x = x` is the same as `f = \x -> x`, so `= \` is sort of the same as `defun`. In Haskell, functions and variables are the same, but they also aren't.

Comment: I would say that functions are just values, but there are other things that are values, too.

Comment: Dammit, ***functions and variables are NOT the same*** in Haskell. (Please read Conal Elliot's post, http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell/)

Comment: "Function" is a semantic notion, while "variable" is a syntactic notion. And, as luqui said, function values and non-function values are all values (not variables). Some variables are function-typed and some variables are not function-typed.

Comment: Jonathan: thanks for the plug. And my last name has two "t"s.

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone indicate any other language with a system similar to Haskell?

Several languages have *immutable variables* (i.e. variables in the mathematical sense) by default:

- Haskell (obviously),
- Clean,
- Erlang,
- ML.

Others encourage this behavior via 'const' or 'val' declarations (Scala, C).

In many functional languages mutable values may only be introduced via explicit 'ref' or 'var' declarations.

Answer (score 1):

In Clojure defn is just a macro to def. Vars are immutable and they hold values. Functions are just values just like any other kind of value. Whether a value actually *is* a function (Fn) is not important as whether that type of value *implements* the function interface (IFn).

To clarify the last point a Java primitive array is not a function. I may wish to treat it as a Clojure Sequence, I could create a wrapper type that allows me to present that interface (ISeq) over the primitive array. I could also have the wrapper type implement IFn and the primitive array could then be treated as a function as well.

```
(def x (wrap-prim-array ...))

(nth x 0) ; idiomatic random access
(x 0)     ; used as a function
```

Answer (score -6):

Don't forget Javascript.

```
var a = function(x) { return (x + 1) };
var b = a(1);
// b == 2 here.
```

is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Not my downvotes, but Javascript variables aren't immutable by default which was the main thrust of the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question was edited so often that this answer is no longer appropriate. I agree with the down votes given the new question but I'm pretty sure I responded to a very different question.

Comment: Yep, perusing the edits shows the following very substantial edit to the title of this question. The question title used to be "Equality of functions and variables like Haskell", which I took to be a question about first class functions. By the way, I have a love/hate relationship with JavaScript but a purely loving relationship with Haskell. It's still my favourite programming language.